# fontconfig support using ImageMagick on R

Tags: r, configuration, package, imagemagick

I want to annotate several images with a custom font using the `magick` package. When I load in the package, I get this:

```
Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.9.14
Enabled features: cairo, freetype, fftw, ghostscript, lcms, pango, rsvg, webp
Disabled features: fontconfig, x11
```

My understanding is that the `fontconfig` feature must be enabled to use my custom font. However, I have not been able to find a way to enable this feature on R.

If anyone familiar with magick could point me in the right direction of how to solve this problem, I would highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using? If you installed `magick` from CRAN on a Mac or Windows based system you should be able to use all installed fonts.

It looks like it's only necessary to install `fontconfig` on UNIX based systems.
Source: [Enabling fontconfig](https://github.com/ropensci/magick/issues/245)

It might just be a matter of using the right name to call the font. Here's a tutorial on how to see all the font names and previews:

[Preview Fonts in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/103617-preview-fonts-windows-10-a.html)

I'm able to all the installed fonts on Windows 10 Home Build 19041.685